# Pattern for avoiding duplicating form content when using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am seeking to find a clean solution to the following antipattern with my AngularJs app:

I have two forms (located in two different templates/partials as of now) which are completely identical **but for the `ng-submit` attributes which point to different Angular controller methods**.

**First form**:

```
<form ng-submit="saveTraining()" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

        <div ng-hide="trainingInfo.statusOK" class="alert alert-danger form-group">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="error in trainingInfo.errors">{{error.message}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="description">descr</label>
            <div class="controls col-lg-6">
                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="description" ng-model="trainingInfo.training.description" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

**Second form** is identical but for the `ng-submit` attribute which is as follows: `ng-submit="editTraining()"`

I would be very grateful if someone who has met the same issue with AngularJs forms could suggest a best practice to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive that uses the form as a template. The directive can bind to a submit function and use that in the template.

Directive:

```
app.directive('myForm', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<form ng-submit="submit()"><button type="submit">Press me</button></form>',
    replace: true,
    scope:
    {
      submit: '&'
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<my-form submit="submitOne()"></my-form>
<my-form submit="submitTwo()"></my-form>
```

Simple demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ERdxGJKrb9JRIWslMJkP?p=preview

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks a lot. I am going to try and test that and keep you posted!